# Laravel 5.4 Passing an array to all the views

Tags: arrays, laravel-5.4

This is the first time i ask for help. I am not a developer or anything close, my knowledge in PHP and Laravel is weak. I am creating a web app and i need to get a value from an array that i have created, but i keep getting an error of "undefined variable" in all the cases i have tried.

I want to filter the items in the sidebar. i am using role as the filter.
The sidebar is an include, that is being called inside a `default.blade.php`, in it's turn, the view `home.blade.php` extends the default.

If i declare the $usersrole in my HomeController, i can see that the sidebar is fine. But if i click any link i get the error "Undefined variable".
The HomeController is like this:

```
...
$userrole = DB::table('users')->where('id','=', Auth::id())->value('role'); 
$menucase1 = [3,4,9,10]; 
$menucase2 = [1,2,3,10];
$menucase3 = [1,3,4,9,10]; 
$menucase4 = [4,9]; 
return view('home', compact('tasks','user','tasktypes','userrole','menucase1','menucase2','menucase3','menucase4'));
```

So i thought, i am going to need all those variables in all the pages, the solution i have found was to create a BaseController in witch i declare the array, like this:

```
$userrole = array (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', Auth::id())->value('role'));
$menucase1 = [3,4,9,10];
$menucase2 = [1,2,3,10];
$menucase3 = [1,3,4,9,10]; 
$menucase4 = [4,9];
$commondata = array_merge($userrole,$menucase1,$menucase2,$menucase3,$menucase4);
View::share('commondata', $commondata);
```

All the other controllers will extend the BaseController. But i still get the same Undefined Variable error.

So i have tried another solution, creating a service provider, declaring the service in config\app.php. I have declared the same array from before inside the `boot()` function.

In my views i am trying to get the value of `$userrole` like this `{{ $commondata->$userrole }}` and i keep getting the same undefined variable error.

At this time i believe the solution might be easy, one of those that will make me feel dumb, but i can't find the solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers). Inside the service provider that you created try adding this code

```
View::composer('sidebar', function ($view) {
    $userrole = array (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', Auth::id())->value('role'));
    $menucase1 = [3,4,9,10];
    $menucase2 = [1,2,3,10];
    $menucase3 = [1,3,4,9,10]; 
    $menucase4 = [4,9];
    $commondata = compact('userrole','menucase1','menucase2','menucase3','menucase4');
    $view->with('commondata', $commondata);
});
```

Now whenever Laravel attempts to render the `sidebar` blade it will make the `$commondata` variable available in the view. In the view you can access the value with `{{ $commondata[0] }}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately i got the same error. maybe its the way i call for the value in the view:  {{ $commondata->$userrole }}

Comment: Are you only using `$commondata` in the sidebar? If not try changing `View::composer('sidebar', function ($view) {...})` to `View::composer('default', function ($view) {...})`

Comment: @MarcoAssunção Also note that `$commondata` is an array, not an object so you should use `{{ $commondata['userrole'] }}` Even if it was an object you should not have the `$` in front of userrole, like `{{ $commondata->userrole }}`

Comment: Something changed :) Now i get the message Undefined index userrole. i am filtering the role like this `@if (in_array($commondata['userrole'], $menucase1))
                            <li><a href="{{URL::to('tasks')}}">Tasks Overview</a></li>
                        @endif`

Comment: @MarcoAssunção do a `{{ dd($commondata) }}` to see the structure of the variable and to make sure it's being loaded properly. Now that I think about it array merge isn't making an associative array so the user role may be in `$commondata[0]`.

Comment: Here's the result of dd($commondata) : `array:16 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 3
  2 => 4
  3 => 9
  4 => 10
  5 => 1
  6 => 2
  7 => 3
  8 => 10
  9 => 1
  10 => 3
  11 => 4
  12 => 9
  13 => 10
  14 => 4
  15 => 9
]`

Comment: @MarcoAssunção try replacing `array_merge` with `compact`, That will build an associative array with the variable names as the key name. Then you can access the user role like `$commondata['userrole']`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Still getting undefined index, i have noticed in the error message that my array is returning `null` in the first position, here's the result `'commondata' => array(null, 3, 4, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 10, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 4, 9),`

Comment: @MarcoAssunção did you actually change the code to `compact('userrole','menucase1','menucase2','menucase3','menucase4')`? Because that is not the result you should be getting if you're using compact.

Comment: it seems the error is coming from another controller, since it says `'tasks' => object(Collection), 'tasktypes' => object(Builder), 'menucase1' => array(3, 4, 9, 10), 'menucase2' => array(1, 2, 3, 10), 'menucase3' => array(1, 3, 4, 9, 10), 'menucase4' => array(4, 9))) ` and i am not passing tasktypes in any of the files we've been talking about. I have my code all messed up... ill get back to you once i find the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: just one more thing. the sidebar will be rendered as soon as i log in into my app, right? at that point, and keeping everything as we talked before... will the userrole be available for the sidebar?